# Is there a word that describes both “providing” and “utilizing”?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, business-language

**Original Question:**

I'm working on a personal 'Purpose Statement'. I would like to make it flow and be succinct. The statement is

Purpose:
To make software more meaningful by providing and utilizing my framework for embedding meaning in code.

I would like to use just one word instead of 'providing and utilizing'. In the business world it seems that these concepts could be merged, but if so I can't think of an appropriate word.

**Edits:**

Proffering is a little bit of an answer to this question:
An offer made; something proposed for acceptance by another; a tender 
(law) Something that is offered into evidence; an offer to which one is willing to testify under oath. 
Essay; attempt.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proffer#English'

Proferring is even better but it's obscure and doesn't pass my browser's spell check test.
1. To utter; to pronounce.
2. To deliver.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/profer#English

Both words are pretty obscure for business.

Another word that comes close is engage:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/engage
1. To interact socially.
    - To engross or hold the attention of; to keep busy or occupied. 
    - To attract, to please; (archaic) to fascinate or win over (someone). 
3. To interact contractually.
    - (intransitive) To guarantee or promise (to do something).

Engage word sounds good in business and may be as close as I can get. So

**Best So Far:**

Purpose: To make software more meaningful by engaging with others in my framework for embedding meaning in code

Purpose: To make software more meaningful by sharing my framework for embedding meaning in code.

Comment: Once you have provided it, do you still have control over it to 'utilize' it ? If not, then once you have provided it, the customer utilizes it.

Comment: The framework is open source, so people can use it for what they want. I want to use it too, to write programs for people as an employee or consultant. I would also like to see the framework widely used. Perhaps having this dual desire is what's making this purpose statement difficult.

Comment: If the framework is open source, then you cannot say 'providing my framework' I would have thought.

Comment: Perhaps 'utilizing and promoting' works better than 'providing and utilizing'

Comment: How does "utilizing" your own framework make software "more meaningful"? I suspect the answer would be different from how "providing" your framework makes software "more meaningful".

Comment: It is the framework itself that allows meaning to be embedded in code. Using the framework allows a programmer to do this. The 'how' is by allowing programmers to assign machine-processable meanings to various data structure instances. Promoting the framework encourages other programmers to do this. I'm a programmer so I can do this using the framework. Others are programmers so they can do this using the framework.

Comment: Embedding meaning in code allows programmers to directly address the things that users care about in code, rather than the current way things are done in which there is no economically feasible way to express what users care about in code in a machine-processable way  most of the time. Huge companies can throw huge amounts of money at what users care about and make some progress but most companies don't have these sorts of resources. Giants Google, Apple, Facebook and Twitter can do it using lots of money, but I want everyone to be able to do it.

Comment: I take it you invented the framework, which is why you call it "your" framework?

Comment: Yes, that is true, I invented it. The current name of the framework is 'The Information Library' or 'InformationLib'. That is a bit of an old name since as the framework has progressed, it has moved in the direction of working with meaning in addition to information. I do not have an up to date name for it at the moment. It is available on GitHub.

Comment: I think the library is at https://github.com/jonrgroverlib/InformationLib

Answer (score 1):

I think the humble word [***share***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/share) might suit your purposes. Its more basic definitions seem applicable (M-W):

> transitive verb
>
> 1. a. : to partake of, use, experience, occupy, or enjoy with others
>      ...
> 2. : to grant or give a share in —often used with *with* • *shared* the last of her water with us
> 3. : to tell (thoughts, feelings, experiences, etc.) to others —often used with *with*

If I "share my lunch" with someone, I'm both providing the lunch to the other person and partaking in it myself. In this case, you are *giving* a share of your framework to others via the open source licensing, and also partaking of it with them when you use it to write programs for them. And I think the "tell about" and more recent, social-media senses of "sharing" also help convey the sense of "promoting" the thing being shared. So:

> Purpose: To make software more meaningful by **sharing** my framework for embedding meaning in code.

Comment: This is the best one so far. And it is so simple! Sometimes it's the hardest thing to do to think of something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the greatest word for your overall purpose, but the closest thing I could think of was "dogfooding." Basically, it's the practice of a company using its own product.

[Wikipedia Entry for Dogfooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food)

That being said, I get the impression that you're thinking more along the lines of "promoting" your framework.

Comment: I love the idea of 'dogfooding' and yet I need a word that will make sense for those who are not steeped in geek culture (like me). My desire is to both use and promote the framework for other people to use. So promote does not quite cover it. Perhaps I have not yet developed enough to see that what I'm really doing is promoting it. I may want to use a word that means something like 'exampling' - me building examples with the framework in order to promote it to other to use.